# Is it possible to transfer Late-2011 MacBook Pro 15" SSD to new late-2016 iMac as primary drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, imac, ssd, maintenance

My personal Late-2011 15" MBP is having issues and I'm considering replacing it with an iMac (either early/late 2016).

If I did decide to get an iMac, would I be able to simply put my MBP SSD into the new iMac, set it as my boot drive, and have a reasonable expectation that it would just work?  If not, is it even possible?  If possible, what is typically involved?

Comment: Ummm you know that the last iMac was actually released in 2015?

Comment: And to answer your question, not really. While I believe it is technically possible to move the drive and the drive would function normally in the iMac, the logistics of getting to the port for the drive is so ridiculously difficult I would highly discourage it. Best thing to do would be to get an iMac and use migration assistant to transfer your data to the new machine

Comment: @NoahL - no, I didn't know that.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: To swap a drive in an iMac, you have to remove a $1000+ screen which is held in place with adhesive.  The cost/benefit of doing this to avoid doing a fresh install is simply not worth the risk of damaging that screen.  Just my $0.02